# Why my KivyMD app Crashes On Startup after converting to Android with Buildozer?

Tags: java, kivy, crash, kivymd, buildozer

I have built an APP from Python Kivy & KivyMD, using Buildozer. It was converted to an APK file successfully. But when I open the app after installing, it is loaded a little while and crashes. Nothing Shows and nothing happens.

I tried with many ways such as using of Google Colab, Using Github Repository. But nothing was succeed.

Please Help me to resolve the issue.

**main.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, SlideTransition
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from functions import *
from plyer import filechooser
from kivy import platform

if platform == "android":
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    request_permissions([Permission.CAMERA, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])

Window.size = (414, 896)

class MyApp(MDApp):
    dialog = None

    def build(self):

        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        self.theme_cls.secondary_palette = "Black"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"

        Builder.load_file('screens/menuutama.kv')
        Builder.load_file('screens/enkripsi.kv')
        Builder.load_file('screens/dekripsi.kv')  # Load the MenuDekripsi kv file
        Builder.load_file('screens/bantuan.kv')  # Load the BantuanPengguna kv file
        Builder.load_file('screens/tentang.kv')

        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(MenuUtama(name='menuutama'))
        screen_manager.add_widget(MenuEnkripsi(name='enkripsi'))
        screen_manager.add_widget(MenuDekripsi(name='dekripsi'))
        screen_manager.add_widget(BantuanPengguna(name='bantuan'))
        screen_manager.add_widget(TentangAplikasi(name='tentang'))
        return screen_manager
    
    def on_start(self, **kwargs):
        if platform == "android":
            from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
            request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
    
    def file_chooser(self):
        filechooser.open_file(on_selection=self.selected)

    #and another code
```

**buildozer.spec**

```
title = ImSecure

# (str) Package name
package.name = imsecure

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,kv,png,jpg,bmp

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1


# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

# (list) Permissions
# (See https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#build-options-1 for all the supported syntaxes and properties)
android.permissions = WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

can you guys help me?

Comment: Try connecting your phone to your PC and running `buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > my_log.txt`. Then look in `my_log.txt` for hints.

Answer (score 0):

Try collab using this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BZv4XslhqGtHJG0jEmcYo1rbk1TI1hiC?usp=sharing) and in generated buildozer.spec file on line 40 use

> requirements = python3, kivy==2.1.0, kivymd==1.1.1, sdl2_ttf==2.0.15, pillow

let me know after trying.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).